# Orange Liveobjects - Data tab > Kibana button always give 403 permission denied error

Tags: kibana, orange-api

while pressing kibana button in data tab I'm always getting error page with permission denied, I've checked the user's roles and found that it has reading access to kibana role,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means that Kibana has not been provisioned correctly on your account. If you contact Live Objects support, they will repair it.

regards

Comment: I've sent them an email and they fixed it, thanks for your help !